# Hide Command Prompt When Executing An EXE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, command-line

Alright, so here's command I'm currently running. Upon executing, a command prompt apprears until the command is finished.

Is there any way to hide the command prompt?

```
Process.Start(
    "\\path_to_exe\Testing.exe ",
    Arg2 + Arg3 + Arg4 + Arg5 + Arg6 + Arg7 + Arg8 + Arg9 + Arg10 + Arg11)
```

Comment: Do you mean 'do not show the command Console' (CLI) at all?

Comment: Have you try this: `Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Dim p as New ProcessStartInfo(@"command", args)
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
p.CreateNoWindow = true
Process.Start(p)
```

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for but I am getting some syntax errors. Looking into them now.

Comment: Remove WindowStyle, add UseShellExecute = false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure why I was getting syntax errors based on @juergen d's answer but I found this and it seems to work just as well.

```
Dim psInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("path_to_exe", Arg2 + Arg3 + Arg4 + Arg5 + Arg6 + Arg7 + Arg8 + Arg9 + Arg10 + Arg11)
    psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell("cmd.exe", AppWinStyle.Hide)

Comment: explain what it will do